# NHibernate - Add Comment Property to Entities (Store with Join)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a system where I need to be able to add a Comment field onto Customer and Location models but I cannot touch the schema of the existing tables. However, I can add a Comments table. I have simplified this example. We would like the ability to add this Comment to more models moving forward they all use a Guid as Id.

This existing system is a 3rd party system with its own data access layer.

We are just starting to get into NHibernate. From what I can tell it looks like a Join map.

Example:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}    

public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Note: we are sure we want the Comment as a 1-to-1 relationship and not a 1-to-many.

How do I configure a separate table just capture Id and Comment? I'm looking for the right terminology to use. I'm looking for examples with XML (and if possible Fluent config). I would like to keep the Comments for all objects in one table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add Comment table (and corresponding key columns in the existing tables) than fluent mapping can look like

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>{
  public CustomerMap(){
        //...other columns mappings

        References(c=>c.Comment).Column("CommentId");
  }
}
```

And repeat it for other entities as well. You can set desired fetch-mode(join) and other action there as well. I have wrote `References` there (so many-to-one) but if you need one-to-one mapping it is not a big difference

Comment: What does the one-to-one mapping look like?

Comment: change `References` to `HasOne`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the database schema your options are very limited.
MAYBE, you can do it using the  mapping.
Take a look here:

http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join

Try to use the same column name in mapping for all entities.

Comment: Do you know is there a way to tell the system through the config that the main entity is not mutable but the "join" is mutable?

Comment: @brun: What do you mean? If na entity is not mutable then there's no way any part of it could mutate.

Comment: There is the Customer part that I don't want to mutate the Comment property is fine. Do I just enforce that with private "sets" on those properties like I show in my C# above?

Comment: @brun: If you don't want to a property to not be updateded, you can set it to update="false" in the mapping. I'm not sure if I'm getting what you need. :)